# Building iOS app with flutter build ipa fails with release

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart, ipa

I have a flutter app I'm working on. When I debug to simulator, it runs perfectly but when I try to build an iOS ipa using `flutter build ipa` I get this weird error.

**P.S:** Building was working before not until I upgraded to flutter version 3, and also upgraded my XCode.

```
octacore@Octacores-MBP AmazeMobile % flutter build ipa
Archiving com.temple.amaze...
Updating project for Xcode compatibility.
Upgrading Runner.xcscheme
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: N76VZU3VL6
Running pod install...                                              6.0s
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode archive done.                                         27.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2022-05-29 17:25:16.334 xcodebuild[36388:1959108] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for
    extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2022-05-29 17:25:16.334 xcodebuild[36388:1959108] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for
    extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/j9/d3bdl9pd4cx2x5jtllbvhcr00000gp/T/flutter_tools.FPXk4X/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir9ZVOeM/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/octacore/Documents/Projects/AmazeMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/octacore/Documents/Projects/AmazeMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'ObjectMapper' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/octacore/Documents/Projects/AmazeMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/octacore/Documents/Projects/AmazeMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/octacore/Documents/Projects/AmazeMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/octacore/Documents/Projects/AmazeMobile/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of
    supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.5.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/j9/d3bdl9pd4cx2x5jtllbvhcr00000gp/T/flutter_tools.FPXk4X/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir9ZVOeM/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CompileSwiftSources failed with a nonzero exit code


Error (Xcode): Framework not found Flutter


Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

Comment: What is your provision profile and sign section in XCode config?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

I've been able to resolve the issue..

1. Downgraded my xcode version to 13.3.
2. Downgraded flutter version to 2.10.4.

That fixed it.